# How do I get a Symfony 6 service from a Codeception Event Handler

Tags: symfony, codeception

I'm getting a "Module is not enabled" when trying to get the Symfony module from within a Codeception EventSubscriber.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/tacman/codeception-symfony-demo  && cd codeception-symfony-demo
composer install
symfony server:start -d
vendor/bin/codecept run -v

In Extension.php line 123:
                                                  
  [Codeception\Exception\ModuleRequireException]  
  [Symfony] module requirements not met --        
                                                  
  module is not enabled                           
                                                  

Exception trace:
  at /home/tac/survos/play/codeception-symfony-demo/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Extension.php:123
 Codeception\Extension->getModule() at /home/tac/survos/play/codeception-symfony-demo/src/EventSubscriber/LoggerSubscriber.php:36
```

The subscriber

```php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Codeception\Event\SuiteEvent;
use Codeception\Events;
use Codeception\Extension;
use Codeception\Module\Symfony;  // smell test, something's wrong...
use Codeception\Step;
use Twig\Environment;


class LoggerSubscriber  extends Extension implements EventSubscriberInterface //
{

    // Not autowired correctly, so set config and options to []
    public function __construct(protected array $config=[], protected array $options=[])
    {
        parent::__construct($config, $options);
    }

    public function afterSuite(SuiteEvent $e)
    {
        /** @var Symfony $symfony */
        $symfony = $this->getModule('Symfony');
        $twig = $symfony->grabService('twig');
        assert($twig, "Twig is not loaded");
    }
```

The configuration is pretty straightforward, adding the LoggerSubscriber event

```yaml
# codeception.yml

namespace: App\Tests
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
        - App\EventSubscriber\LoggerSubscriber: # enabled extension
              max_files: 5 # logger configuration

params:
    - .env

# acceptance.suite.yml
#
# Suite for acceptance tests.

actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
              part: services
              app_path: 'src'
              environment: 'dev'
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost:8000
        - \App\Tests\Helper\Acceptance
# functional_suite.yml
#
# Suite for functional tests
# Emulate web requests and make application process them
# Include one of framework modules (Symfony2, Yii2, Laravel5) to use it

actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
            part: services
            app_path: 'src'
            environment: 'test'
        - \App\Tests\Helper\Functional
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the codeception modules found in the [`composer.json`](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/69f5c85d0c733826395271566a7677d2bc19bd21/composer.json) of `codeception/codeception` and the [Symfony module](https://github.com/Codeception/module-symfony).

```bash
composer require --dev \
  codeception/module-asserts \
  codeception/module-cli \
  codeception/module-db \
  codeception/module-filesystem \
  codeception/module-phpbrowser \
  codeception/module-symfony
```

The [readme.md](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/5.0.2/readme.md#composer) states:

> TODO: Document how to install the modules

I'd recommend using the PHAR archive of `codeception`.

It's usage prevents dependency conflicts with your application.

Comment: Alas, I've already those dependencies, and it's still not working.  I now think its a Codeception bug.